# Llamar a elemento de array en PHP

Tags: php, array

Estoy haciendo un "mini" sistema que actualiza los partidos del día. Lo hice con un `array` que ya armé: este tiene 24 equipos.
La idea es desde un panel actualizar solo el elemento a llamar (Por ejemplo: `echo $equipos[17];` cambiar el "17")

Acá está donde se muestra:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><center><img height="40px" src="imagenes/escudos/<?php echo $escudos[17]; ?>.png"></center></th>
      <th><center><?php echo $equipos[17]; ?></center></th>
      <th><center>-</center></th>
      <th><center><?php echo $equipos[22]; ?></center></th>
      <th><center><img height="40px" src="imagenes/escudos/<?php echo $escudos[22]; ?>.png"></center></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Ya se que tengo el mismo vector pero con los escudos. Usa las mismas posiciones, significa que voy a poder lo mismo para llamar a las posiciones en los `array's`.
Tengo la idea pero no se, ni encontré nada que realmente cumpla con lo que necesite.
El "panel" por ahora que esté en un directorio sin contraseña ni nada.

Por ahora eso, si no expliqué algo, avísenme y trataré de explicarlo un poco mejor. Muchas gracias!

**PD: Sé que el código no está muy optimizado, pero es una prueba, la idea es después ir mejorándolo.**

Comment: Y cuál es el error? cómo sabes qué elemento quieres llamar? Debes de ser un poco más específico de lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Yo me refiero a hacer como un panel que tenga 2 imputs: uno para el local y otro para el visitante. Ya sabiendo previamente cual es el numero que identifica a cada equipo

Comment: Me dejaste igual, si quieres saber cuál es el número que le pertenece a cada equipo crea un [array asociativo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php) así le agregas la clave que en este caso número que tu deseas a cada equipo.

Comment: Yo ya se cual es el numero que identifica a cada equipo, pero en vez de ponerlo `$equipos[17]` quiero que el numero de corchetes ponerlo a travez del navegador y guardarlo, porque cada semana voy a tener que editarlo ese numero. Quiero crear una especie de admin donde con un formulario o algo parecido poner el numero ahi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres, pero si me parece una mala idea tener los datos de forma fragmentada, ya que eso puede crear inconsistencia si en algún momento se puede insertar o borrar datos de un arreglo, pero no en el otro.
Sugeriría que usaras arreglos (arrays) asociativos para mantener todos los datos de una entidad íntegros.
Ejemplo

```
<?php

$equipos = array(
1=>array('nombre'=>'Primavera FC', 'escudo'=>'pr2019.jpg', 'dt'=>'Juan Perez'), 
2=>array('nombre'=>'Los Naranjos', 'escudo'=>'naran2019.jpg', 'dt'=>'[ POR DEFINIR ]'), 
);

// Podemos agregar otro equipo
$equipos[3] = array('nombre'=>'FC Reds', 'escudo'=>'reds2019.jpg', 'dt'=>'Pedro Gonzalez');

// El equipo 2 no tiene técnico, lo podemos actualizar
$equipos[2]['dt'] = 'Jose Rivera';

// Podemos listar todos los equipos con su escudo y técnico
foreach($equipos as $key=>$value) {
    echo 'id: ' . $key;
    echo ' | Nombre: ' . $value['nombre'];
    echo ' | Escudo: ' . $value['escudo'];
    echo ' | Director: ' . $value['dt'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Lo cual producirá:

> ```
> id: 1 | Nombre: Primavera FC | Escudo: pr2019.jpg | Director: Juan Perez
> id: 2 | Nombre: Los Naranjos | Escudo: naran2019.jpg | Director: Jose Rivera
> id: 3 | Nombre: FC Reds | Escudo: reds2019.jpg | Director: Pedro Gonzalez
> ```

Comment: Está bien. La idea es cambiar el equipo desde el navegador (con javascript)

Answer (score 2):

A explicación de tu ultimo comentario, te dejo lo siguiente:

Teniendo en cuenta que para acceder a los elementos de un array se empieza desde el número **0**, sí tú quieres cambiar el equipo '17' haciendo tu cuenta normal empezando desde el `1` entonces tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php 

$equipos = array(); //tu variable con los 24 equipos

$contador = 1;

for($i = 0; $i < count(equipos); $i++){

echo 'Indice: '.$contador.' Su valor: '.$equipos[$i];

 $contador++;
}

?>
```

Y te propongo utilices mejor un `<select>` así iteras el indice y lo colocas en el atributo `<option value="$contador">$equipos[$i]</option>`. y el nombre como texto. Solamente que si vas a actualizar el array de los equipos mediante el índice, por ejemplo si quieres actualizar el equipo en tu conteo normal empezando por `1` si quieres actualizar el `16` en la posición del array sería el `17` entonces tendrías que restarle **1** al índice **O PARA NO COMPLICARSE LA VIDA, ARMA UN ARRAY ASOCIATIVO $equipos = array(1 => "Equipo1", 2=> "Equipo2",..., n => "Equipon");** Y puedes utilizar un [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php).

Se me ocurrió algo como esto, cada que des click en siguiente fecha te va a armar la fecha, está en forma estática, porque de forma dinámica me iba a tardar más :c espero te de una idea.

```js
var equipos1 = new Array('FC lobos', 'Juquilas', 'Niupy'); //tu variable con los 24 equipos
var equipos2 = new Array('Leones Negros', 'Aztecas', 'Barza');

var click = 0;

document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', function(){

switch(click){

case 0:

  console.log(`${equipos1[0]} VS ${equipos2[0]}`);
  console.log(`${equipos1[1]} VS ${equipos2[1]}`);
  console.log(`${equipos1[2]} VS ${equipos2[2]}`);
break;


case 1:

  console.log(`${equipos1[0]} VS ${equipos2[2]}`);
  console.log(`${equipos1[1]} VS ${equipos1[2]}`);
  console.log(`${equipos2[1]} VS ${equipos2[0]}`);
break;


}
  


click++;

});
```

```html
<button id="click">Siguiente fecha</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, no estaría entendiendo que hace exactamente eso.

Comment: Qué parte no entiendes? Con gusto te explico. :)

Comment: Yo al array lo tengo ordenado alfabéticamente, osea: el equipo en la posicion 19(sería el local) se enfrenta al equipo 3(visitante). Si no mal entiendo ahi lo haces con un indice, donde el local tendria que ser un numero mas chico que el visitante. Me refiero como en el ejemplo, `$equipo[19] vs $equipo[3]` con tu solucion quedaria  `$equipo[3] vs $equipo[19] ` . Tendria yo que ordenar el array cada semana para que el local siempre tenga un numero menor al visitante?

Comment: No, nunca escribí eso, y si te das cuenta `$equipo[19] vs $equipo[3]` y esto `$equipo[3] vs $equipo[19]` es lo mismo, solamente tú le das el sentido de quién es local y quién es visitante, no tienes que ordenar nada, creo que no te estás planteando bien el problema, si tu quieres **ACTUALIZAR** un equipo qué es lo que debes de saber? si es local o visitante? **NO**, sólo debes saber qué posición tiene en el array.

Comment: Ok. pero lo que yo no entiendo es como cambiar el identificador `"[xx]"` desde el navegador, sin tener que entrar al sublime text cada semana.

Comment: Por ahí hubiéramos empezado... Lo quieres cambiar para por ejemplo actualizarlo en la tabla, si estamos hablando de fútbol, en la tabla de posiciones? Si es así lo tendrías que hacer mediante javascript para cambiarlo desde el FRONTEND. O todo este lío hacer con JavaScript para que no tengas que pasar al servidor y actualizar tu array, con JS también puedes manejar Arreglos.

Comment: Claro algo asi. pero no una tabla de posiciones, Si no, los partidos de cada fecha.

Comment: Pues lo partidos de cada Fecha, ya deberían estar establecidos desde un principio, o los quieres hacer aleatorios? Eso llevaría un par de días resolverlo para mí que no soy un experto. XD

Comment: Yo quiero por ejemplo un martes cambiar el identificador de cada equipo, asi se actualiza con el siguiente fecha, y esto hacerlo desde el navegador.

Comment: Ya te hice un ejemplo espero te de una idea.

Answer (score 1):

Para llamar a un elemento de un array en PHP **se utiliza su posición en arrays no asociativos**, teniendo en cuenta que la primera posición es la 0, o **su índice si es un array asociativo**.

**Ejemplo llamada al tercer elemento de un array:**

```
$array = [
    'manzana',
    'pera',
    'uva',
];
echo $array[2]; // uva
```

**Ejemplo llamada a un elemento de un array asociativo:**

```
$array_asoc = [
    'primero' => 'manzana',
    'segundo' => 'pera',
    'tercero' => 'uva',
];
echo $array_asoc['tercero']; // uva
```

Hay que señalar, que ***en ambos casos, si se llama a un índice inexistente se producirá una notificación***:

```
Notice</b>:  Undefined index: ...
```

por ejemplo:

```
echo $array[5]; // Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in ..
echo $array_asoc['xxx']; // Notice:  Undefined index: xxx in ...
```